# Satisfy() in Fluent Assertions does not work with collections of class objects

Tags: c#, assertion, fluent-assertions

I have a class:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public int CampusId { get; set; }
    
    public int CurrentStudentCount { get; set; }
    
    public int MaxStudentCount { get; set; }
}
```

and a collection of objects of this class:

```
var collection = new[]
    {
        new TestClass
        {
            Id = 55,
            CampusId = 38,
            CurrentStudentCount = 1,
            MaxStudentCount = 2
        },
        new TestClass
        {
            Id = 127,
            CampusId = 38,
            CurrentStudentCount = 2,
            MaxStudentCount = 2
        },
        new TestClass
        {
            Id = 126,
            CampusId = 38,
            CurrentStudentCount = 2,
            MaxStudentCount = 2
        }
    };
```

I'd like to assert that each object's `CampusId` equals 38:

```
collection.Should().Satisfy(i => i.CampusId == 38);
```

But the assertion fails with the following message:

**Expected collection to satisfy all predicates, but the following elements did not match any predicate:**

```
Index: 1, Element: TestClass

{
    CampusId = 38, 
    CurrentStudentCount = 2, 
    Id = 127, 
    MaxStudentCount = 2
}

Index: 2, Element: TestClass

{
    CampusId = 38, 
    CurrentStudentCount = 2, 
    Id = 126, 
    MaxStudentCount = 2
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `AllSatisfy()`, which was added in v. 6.5.0 as per https://fluentassertions.com/collections/.

In your case, it would be:

```
collection.Should().AllSatisfy(
    i => i.CampusId.Should().Be(38)
);
```

Comment: and I was trying it with `i => i.CampusId == 38`. Thanks, now it works :)

Answer (score 10):

`Satisfy` (and `SatisfyRespectively`) requires a lambda for each element in a collection. In your case that would be:

```cs
collection.Should().Satisfy(
    i => i.CampusId == 38,
    i => i.CampusId == 38,
    i => i.CampusId == 38
);
```

The other option would be to use `OnlyContain`:

```cs
collection.Should().OnlyContain(i => i.CampusId == 38);
```

---

**Update**

With version `6.5.0` it is also possible to use `AllSatisfy`:

```cs
collection.Should().AllSatisfy(i => i.CampusId.Should().Be(38))
```

Comment: Will OnlyContain assert that each element's CampusId equals 38? If yes, can I have more predicates at once? E. g. CampusId == 38 and CurrentStudentCount <= MaxStudentCount?

Comment: Yes, `OnlyContain` asserts that all elements match the predicate.
`collection.Should().OnlyContain(i => i.CampusId == 38 && i.CurrentStudentCount <= i.MaxStudentCount);`.
There's an open issue about having a `AllSatisfy`
https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/issues/1179